# How to remove empty page after appendix and the next chapter?

Tags: appendices, blank-page

I am using LaTeX for my thesis and I am getting a blank page after Appendix and the next chapter. My document class is `book`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}
```

I have tried inserting the following commands in my preamble but it does not seem to work:

```
\makeatletter\@openrightfalse\makeatother
```

and

```
{\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage 
\input{appendix}
}
```

and

```
\csname @openrightfalse\endcsname
```

could someone help me out with this?

Comment: For me I had the title Appendix on a empty page, and the figure started in a new one. I solved it using [h!] command for the figure

Answer (score 13):

If you do not wish to have blank pages after chapters throughout the document, you should be using the `openany` option for the documentclass.  The following gives a two page document with no blank pages

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

When using the `oneside` option this happens already, and the opposite option `openright` has no effect.  The reason for this is that the `openright` option asks the chapter and other commands to use `\cleardoublepage`, but `\cleardoublepage` acts as `\clearpage` for `oneside` documents.

If you wish to have blank pages after chapters in the body of the document, but not in the appendices, then the simplest way is as follows: use standard two side formatting and switch the value of the `openright` option at the appendix:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\chapter{Another Chapter}
\cleardoublepage\makeatletter\@openrightfalse\makeatother
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\chapter{Another Appendix}

\end{document}
```

However, you say you are using the `oneside` option, perhaps for other formatting effects.  Should you wish to keep that, then we need to redefine `\cleardoublepage` so as not to test for the `twoside` option:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage \ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\chapter{Another Chapter}
\cleardoublepage\makeatletter\@openrightfalse\makeatother
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\chapter{Another Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Moving appendix material to an external file and using `\input` will lead to the same results.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for your reply. With the \documentclass[openany]{book}, although I get rid of the blank pages, I also skew the arrangement of rest of my document. With \documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,openany]{book} command, it still does not work. I have my appendix as an external file and i \include{appendix} to the document.

Comment: As Andrew pointed out, you might use `\input` instead of `\include`. `\include` issues a `\clearpage` command before including the file contents, which `\input` does not.

Comment: @Mayur I have updated my answer to address this.

Comment: I had almost given up on the problem (trying to include pdf as a back cover whithout the added blank page) and then two months later I began searching, I tried your solution ... AND IT'S MAGIC.